# Metrics/AbcSize: Assignment Branch Condition size for create is too high. [15.17/15]

Tags: controller, ruby-on-rails-5.2, rubocop

I would prefer to call my JS method directly from controller, but I am getting the following Rubocop error.

Error:

> Metrics/AbcSize: Assignment Branch Condition size for create is too
>   high. [15.17/15]

controller:

```
 def create ...

      def create
        @profile = current_user.profiles.new(modified_profile_params)
        respond_to do |format|
          if @profile.save
            format.html { redirect_to profiles_path }
            format.js { render js: "Helpers.SearchForm.AfterSearchSubmit();" }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.js {
              render js:
                         "Helpers.Bootstrap.Modal.init(
                         'Title',
                         'message','ok',
                         '',
                         '#oldmodal',
                         Helpers.SearchForm.AfterSearchSubmit
                         );"
            }
          end
        end
      end
```

to fix this, I tried the below:

```
def limit_modal_javascript
           {
                  render js:
                             "Helpers.Bootstrap.Modal.init(
                             'Title',
                             'message','ok',
                             '',
                             '#oldmodal',
                             Helpers.SearchForm.AfterSearchSubmit
                             );"
                }
  end
```

however, I then got following error at runtime:

> syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting do or '{' or '(' {render
>   js:

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the syntax error by moving `render` to before the opening `{` in the `limit_modal_javascript` method.

However, there are better ways to structure this. Rather having the JavaScript in the controller, you could move it to a template, e.g. `app/views/products/create_succeeded.js`. You can then render that from the controller with:

```
format.js { render "products/create_succeeded" }
```

Comment: I noticed you has create.succeeded and create_succeeded, is that on purpose?

Comment: It should be "create_succeeded", I've made a correction.